# Real time XChart in JavaFX aaplication

Tags: javafx, xcharts

I'm trying to embedded a XChart panel in a JavaFX application.

For that I'm trying to use a swing node to add to it a xChart panel. So far it works, I can see the chart.

The problem is that I need to update it in realtime every 50 ms and if I try to add the data to the chart it won't update it until later.

```
    final XYChart chart = QuickChart.getChart("Simple XChart Real-time Demo", "Radians", "Sine", "sine", initdata[0], initdata[1]);    


    JPanel pnlChart = new XChartPanel(chart);
```

If I use a SwingWrapper:

```
final SwingWrapper<XYChart> sw = new SwingWrapper<XYChart>(chart);
sw.displayChart();
```

and use sw.repaintChart():

```
Platform.runLater(() -> chart.updateXYSeries("sine", data[0], data[1], null));
sw.repaintChart();
```

It works but the swing Wrapper creates its own window.

How could I update the data in the embedded chart instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`SwingWrapper` is a class designed to pop up a standalone `JFrame` to display a chart and shouldn't be used as an embedded chart in a JavaFX or Swing application. Take a look at [SwingDemo](https://github.com/knowm/XChart/blob/develop/xchart-demo/src/main/java/org/knowm/xchart/standalone/SwingDemo.java) and use a `XChartPanel` in your JavaFX app instead.